# How to throttle matrix configurations in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I need to throttle Matrix configurations in Jenkins declarative pipeline. For now I have a simple matrix like that:

```groovy
    matrix {
      axes {
        axis {
          name 'Test'
          values 'Example1','Example2','Example3'
        }
      }
    }
```

And I can run only five configuration in parallel. First of all I created a *category*:

[image]

And now I'm trying to use throttle job property and there I'm stuck. As I see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/throttleconcurrents/ThrottleJobProperty.java) in order to use throttle matrix configurations we need to pass `matrixOptions` parameters that contains two properties `throttleMatrixBuilds` and `throttleMatrixConfigurations`.

```groovy
    options {
           throttleJobProperty(
           categories: ['ForTestMatrix'],
           throttleEnabled: true,
           throttleOption: 'category',
           matrixOptions: ???
           )
    }
```

Could someone tell me how to pass an object with two properties as a parameter there?

**UPD**
I managed to run this code like that:

```
    options {
           throttleJobProperty(
           categories: ['ForTestMatrix'],
           throttleEnabled: true,
           throttleOption: 'category',
           matrixOptions: new hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleMatrixProjectOptions(false, true)
           )
    }
```

But when I start this job I see in blue ocean that all the matrix configurations start at once. Does anyone have ideas why throttling doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Which type of Jenkins project is this?

Comment: @GeroldBroser that's a pipeline project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Throttle Concurrent Builds](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/#unsupported-use-cases):

> ### Unsupported use cases
>
> This section contains links to the use cases which are **not** supported.
>
> #### Throttling of code blocks without a `node()` definition
>
> ...
>
> #### Throttling Pipeline via job properties
>
> Starting in `throttle-concurrents-2.0`, using this option is not recommended. Use the `throttle()` step instead.

The following pipeline:

```groovy
pipeline {
    
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Matrix') {
            matrix {
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'Example'
                        values 'Example 1','Example 2','Example 3'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Test') {
                        steps {
                            throttle(['ForTestMatrix']) {
                                node( 'master' ) {
                                    sh 'set +x; date; sleep 5; date'
                                }
                            } // throttle
                        } // steps
                    } // stage 'Test'
                } // stages
            } // matrix
        } // stage 'Matrix'
    } // stages
} // pipeline
```

gives this output:

```
                                 ...
[Matrix - Example = 'Example 1'] + set +x
                                 Fri Oct 22 15:54:01 GMT 2021
                                 Fri Oct 22 15:54:06 GMT 2021
                                 ...
[Matrix - Example = 'Example 2'] + set +x
                                 Fri Oct 22 15:54:06 GMT 2021
                                 Fri Oct 22 15:54:12 GMT 2021
                                 ...
[Matrix - Example = 'Example 3'] + set +x
                                 Fri Oct 22 15:54:12 GMT 2021
                                 Fri Oct 22 15:54:17 GMT 2021
                                 ...
```